# Custom table cells to control map view

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have one view controller which contains a mapView and tableView (pictured below). I was wondering if it was possible to click on a table cell and the mapView region would update with its coordinates? I have tried many methods, the main one which seemed promising:

HorizontalTableCell.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSDictionary *currentSelected = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

HomeViewController *mvc = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [[currentSelected objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [[currentSelected objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 1.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 1.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

[mvc.mapView setRegion:region];

//testing, shows which table cell is selected
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", location.latitude, location.longitude];
UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

// Display Alert Message
[messageAlert show];

}
```

The tableView is using a custom table cell, so this method is in its own HorizontalTableCell class (while the mapView is in the HomeViewController class). Selecting a cell works, because the alert gives me the correct coordinates for the selected cell (which grabs the lat and long from an array _articles), but for some reason I can't access or control my mapView in the Home View Controller.

[image: My view controller in question]
The other way I tried was calling a Home View Controller method in the Horizontal Table Cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

HomeViewController.h

```
- (void)changeMapRegion:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coord;
```

HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)changeMapRegion:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (coord, 1.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 1.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    NSLog(@"the coordinates are %f and %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);

    [_mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

}
```

In the HorizontalTableCell.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *currentSelected = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    HomeViewController *mvc = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [[currentSelected objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [[currentSelected objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];

    [mvc changeMapRegion:location];
}
```

When I click on a table cell, the log gives me the correct coordinates, so I am calling the method fine, but the mapView doesn't change its region.. I'm totally stuck! I would love some advice.

Comment: The table view and the map view are in the same view controller, right?  Why is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method in the custom cell's class?  I suggest adding the [ios] tag to the question (remove the didSelectRowAtIndexPath tag).

Comment: Yep, they are both in the same view controller in Storyboards but my table is a custom horizontal table [link] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) **Pulse-style tables**. So it's a table within a table (which is why I called didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the inner table). My main question is if any mapView can be controlled from another class? Thanks, I will change the tag.

Comment: Yes, a map view can be controlled from another class.  They are generally well-behaved Objective-C objects.  You need to obtain a reference to the instance of that class or use delegation or notification.

Comment: I tried to make a delegate protocol for my HomeViewController (to update the mapView region).. but the delegate method would be separate from my HorizontalTableCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, so I'm not sure how to call it. Sorry, do you think you could elaborate on what your thoughts were? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I still don't understand why HorizontalTableCell implements the UITableView delegate (and not HomeViewController where the table view is).  But you could try making HomeViewController the delegate of the HorizontalTableCell and have HorizontalTableCell callback from its didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Then the HomeViewController can update the map which it already has a reference to.